# Increase API timeout in fastapi from docker image

Tags: timeout, gateway, fastapi

I running FastAPI docker image and getting timeouts. The default timeout is 60 seconds. Any idea what will be the simplest way to increase the timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Timeout can be modified by changing the environment variable **TIMEOUT**
You can either set the variable in the command when you build the container or you can add it to your docker compose file.

Here you have more information about it.

[Timeout variable](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#timeout)